# Using pd.to_datetime to convert "object" column into %HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, json, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am doing some exploratory data analysis using finish-time data scraped from the 2018 KONA IRONMAN. I used JSON to format the data and pandas to read into csv. The 'swim','bike','run' columns should be formatted as %HH:MM:SS to be operable, however, I am receiving a ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '--:--:--').

```
print(data.head(2))
print(kona.info())
print(kona.describe())
```

> ```
>      Name div_rank    ...         bike       run
> 0    Avila, Anthony 2470      138    ...     05:27:59  04:31:56
> 1  Lindgren, Mikael 1050      151    ...     05:17:51  03:49:20
>
>      swim            2472 non-null object
>      bike            2472 non-null object
>      run             2472 non-null object
>
>      Name div_rank    ...         bike       run
>      count                2472     2472    ...         2472      2472
>      unique               2472      288    ...         2030      2051
>      top     Jara, Vicente 986       --    ...     --:--:--  --:--:--
>      freq                    1      165    ...          122       165
> ```

How should I use pd.to_datetime to properly format the 'bike','swim','run' column and for future use sum these columns and append a 'Total Finish Time' column? Thanks!

Comment: You think providing all the code will be helpful but it does not. You will get a quicker and more useful response if you keep the code minimum that can replicate your issue.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The issue is it doesn’t know how to parse when there’s no string in the format (needs to have digits in “##:##:##”  time. So you’ll have to do one if two things a) change all the “—:—:—“ to “00:00:00”. If you’re ok with that. Or b) only parse the strings that have actual times and skip the “—:—:—“ rows.

Comment: Also are you sure you want to write the data as “data.txt”? You’re reading in “data.csv”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the error is because it can't pull the time from '--:--:--'. So you'd need to convert all those to '00:00:00', but then that implies they did the event in 0 time. The other option is to just convert the times that are present, leaving a null in the places that don't have a time. This will also include a date of `1900-01-01`, when you convert to `datetime`. I put the `.dt.time` so only time will display.

```
timed_events = ['bike', 'swim', 'run']
for event in timed_events:
    result[event] = pd.to_datetime(result[result[event] != '--:--:--'][event], format="%H:%M:%S").dt.time
```

The problem with this though is I remember seeing you wanted to sum those times, which would require you to do some extra conversions. So I'm suggesting to use `.to_timedelta()` instead. It'll work the same way, as you'd need to not include the `--:--:--`. But then you can sum those times. I also added a column of number of event completed, so that if you want to sort by best times, you can filter out anyone who hasn't competed in all three events, as obviously they'd have better times because they are missing entire events:

I'll also add, regarding the comment of:

> "You think providing all the code will be helpful but it does not. You
>   will get a quicker and more useful response if you keep the code
>   minimum that can replicate your issue.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve –
>   mad_ "

I'll give him the benefit of the doubt as seeing the whole code and not realizing that the code you provided was the minimal code to replicate your issue, as no one wants to code a way to generate your data to work with. Sometimes you can explicitly state that in your question.

ie:

*Here's the code to generate my data:*

```
CODE PART 1

import bs4
import pandas as pd

code...
```

*But now that I have the data, here's where I'm having trouble:*

```
df = pd.to_timedelta()...
...
```

Luckily I remembered helping you earlier on this so knew I could go back and get that code. So the code you originally had was fine.

But here's the full code I used, which is a different way of storing the csv than you orginially had. So you can change that part, but the end part is what you'll need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import pandas as pd

sauce = 'http://m.ironman.com/triathlon/events/americas/ironman/world-championship/results.aspx'

r = requests.get(sauce)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

def parse_table(soup):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    my_table = soup.find('tbody')

    for node in my_table.children:
        if isinstance(node, Comment):
            # Get content and strip comment "<!--" and "-->"
            # Wrap the rows in "table" tags as well.
            data = '<table>{}</table>'.format(node[4:-3])
            break

    table = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        name, _, swim, bike, run, div_rank, gender_rank, overall_rank = [col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td')[1:]]

        result[name].append({
            'div_rank': div_rank,
            'gender_rank': gender_rank,
            'overall_rank': overall_rank,
            'swim': swim,
            'bike': bike,
            'run': run,
        })

    return result

jsonObj = parse_table(soup)

result = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in jsonObj.items():

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v)
    temp_df['name'] = k
    result = result.append(temp_df)

result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
result.to_csv('C:/data.csv', index=False)

# However you read in your csv/dataframe, use the code below on it to get those times
timed_events = ['bike', 'swim', 'run']
for event in timed_events:
    result[event] = pd.to_timedelta(result[result[event] != '--:--:--'][event])

result['total_events_participated'] = 3 - result.isnull().sum(axis=1)
result['total_times'] = result[timed_events].sum(axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (result)
         bike div_rank     ...     total_events_participated total_times
0    05:27:59      138     ...                             3    11:20:06
1    05:17:51      151     ...                             3    10:16:17
2    06:14:45      229     ...                             3    14:48:28
3    05:13:56      162     ...                             3    10:19:03
4    05:19:10        6     ...                             3    09:51:48
5    04:32:26       25     ...                             3    08:23:26
6    04:49:08      155     ...                             3    10:16:16
7    04:50:10      216     ...                             3    10:55:47
8    06:45:57       71     ...                             3    13:50:28
9    05:24:33      178     ...                             3    10:21:35
10   06:36:36       17     ...                             3    14:36:59
11        NaT       --     ...                             0    00:00:00
12   04:55:29      100     ...                             3    09:28:53
13   05:39:18       72     ...                             3    11:44:40
14   04:40:41       --     ...                             2    05:35:18
15   05:23:18       45     ...                             3    10:55:27
16   05:15:10        3     ...                             3    10:28:37
17   06:15:59       78     ...                             3    11:47:24
18        NaT       --     ...                             0    00:00:00
19   07:11:19       69     ...                             3    15:39:51
20   05:49:02       29     ...                             3    10:32:36
21   06:45:48        4     ...                             3    13:39:17
22   04:39:46       --     ...                             2    05:48:38
23   06:03:01        3     ...                             3    11:57:42
24   06:24:58      193     ...                             3    13:52:57
25   05:07:42      116     ...                             3    10:01:24
26   04:44:46      112     ...                             3    09:29:22
27   04:46:06       55     ...                             3    09:32:43
28   04:41:05       69     ...                             3    09:31:32
29   05:27:55       68     ...                             3    11:09:37
      ...      ...     ...                           ...         ...
2442      NaT       --     ...                             0    00:00:00
2443 05:26:40        3     ...                             3    11:28:53
2444 05:04:37       19     ...                             3    10:27:13
2445 04:50:45       74     ...                             3    09:15:14
2446 07:17:40      120     ...                             3    14:46:05
2447 05:26:32       45     ...                             3    10:50:48
2448 05:11:26      186     ...                             3    10:26:00
2449 06:54:15      185     ...                             3    14:05:16
2450 05:12:10       22     ...                             3    11:21:37
2451 04:59:44       45     ...                             3    09:29:43
2452 06:03:59       96     ...                             3    12:12:35
2453 06:07:27       16     ...                             3    12:47:11
2454 04:38:06       91     ...                             3    09:52:27
2455 04:41:56       14     ...                             3    08:58:46
2456 04:38:48       85     ...                             3    09:18:31
2457 04:42:30       42     ...                             3    09:07:29
2458 04:40:54      110     ...                             3    09:32:34
2459 06:08:59       37     ...                             3    12:15:23
2460 04:32:20       --     ...                             2    05:31:05
2461 04:45:03       96     ...                             3    09:30:06
2462 06:14:29       95     ...                             3    13:38:54
2463 06:00:20      164     ...                             3    12:10:03
2464 05:11:07       22     ...                             3    10:32:35
2465 05:56:06      188     ...                             3    13:32:48
2466 05:09:26        2     ...                             3    09:54:55
2467 05:22:15        7     ...                             3    10:26:14
2468 05:53:14      254     ...                             3    12:34:21
2469 05:00:29      156     ...                             3    10:18:29
2470 04:30:46        7     ...                             3    08:38:23
2471 04:34:59       39     ...                             3    09:04:13

[2472 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and guidance chitown88!

Comment: no worries. I like doing this stuff, as it helps me learn, practice, and sometimes can pick up new tricks when others post alternate solutions. cheers!